# How do I divide binary data into frames in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary

I need to read a binary file containing several bytes and divide the contents into frames, each consisting of 535 bytes each. The number of frames present in the file is not known at runtime and thus I need to dynamically allocate memory for them. The code below is a snippet and as you can see, I'm trying to create a pointer to an array of bytes (`uint8_t`) and then increment into the next frame and so on, in the loop that reads the buffered data into the frames. How do I allocate memory at runtime and is this the best way to do the task? Please let me know if there is a more elegant solution. Also, how I manage the memory?

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

long getFileSize(FILE *file)
{
    long currentPosition, endPosition;
    currentPosition = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, 2);
    endPosition = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, currentPosition, 0);
    return endPosition;
}

int main()
{
    const char *filePath = "C:\Payload\Untitled.bin";
    uint8_t *fileBuffer;
    FILE *file = NULL;
    if((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
        cout << "Failure. Either the file does not exist or this application lacks sufficient permissions to access it." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Success. File has been loaded." << endl;
    long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
    fileBuffer = new uint8_t[fileSize];
    fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, file);
    uint8_t (*frameBuffer)[535];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        frameBuffer[j][i] = fileBuffer[i];
        if((i % 534) == 0)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `const char *filePath = "C:\Payload\Untitled.bin";` won't work, because it treats '\P' and '\U' as escape characters. Use double slashes, like this: `"C:\\Payload\\Untitled.bin"`

Comment: "The number of frames" .. isn't simply `fileSize / 535`?

Comment: Oops. Absolutely! Yes. I was just keeping the source generic, since I may have to later convert this into a real time operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct frame {
    unsigned char bytes[535];
};

std::vector<frame> frames;
```

Now your loop can simply read a frame and push it into `frames`. No explicit memory management needed: `std::vector` does that for you.

Comment: Okay. And how would I access the 5th value of the 2nd frame, for example? Would `frames[2][5]` suffice?

Comment: Oh! I just realised. I'd access each the above as frames[2].frame[5], I guess.

Comment: @Siddharth - yes, that will work. But the `frame` that I wrote is just a skeleton. You can't put a C-style array into a `vector`, so I wrapped it in a `struct`. In the real world it should be fleshed out more, and the details depend on what you need to do with it. Generally speaking, `bytes` should be private, and the class should provide appropriate operations. If access to individual bytes is necessary, then it should have `operator[]()`, for example.

Comment: Ah! Yes. That makes perfect sense. One more question, during the `fread` how is the numbers of bits to read at a time from the binary file, determined? As in, in this instance, I'm reading eight at a time to an `uint8_t`. Is there any way to adjust that?

Comment: I think it's better to have a move ctor (if c++11), or copy ctor (use memcpy, for return value optimization). So you can have better performance when add to vecter or pass around.

Comment: @XinHuang - better than what? `<g>` With the definition of `frame` that I gave, there's no benefit from a move constructor, and the compiler-generated copy constructor should work just fine. Speculative optimizations are usually wrong; unless you know that copying is a bottleneck **and** that the compiler-generated copy constructor could be improved on, don't fiddle with it.

Comment: @PeteBecker, could you please the question I posed in the comment above? I would love to hear your ideas or opinions.

Comment: @Siddharth - file I/O is, deep down, about reading and writing bytes. You can't control the number of bits in a byte: that's determined by the hardware. `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` can all hold a byte. `uint8_t` might not; on a system with bytes that aren't 8 bits (not all that common), it won't exist.

Comment: So, do I need to replace the data type then? Is `char` going to be functionally the same in this instance as `uint8_t`? I'm doing some bitwise shifts later in the code.

Comment: @Siddharth - `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the compiler. That means that shifts can be tricky. Use either `unsigned char` (for maximum portability), or `uint8_t` for whatever reason people think that's cool, or `uint_least8_t` for portability.